# To what extent does the chronicity of a tendinopathy impact the outcome of platelet-rich plasma (PRP) injections?

Tags: tendinopathy, epicondylitis, injections, prp

I wonder to what extent the chronicity of a tendinopathy impacts the outcome of platelet-rich plasma (PRP) injections? (outcome = degree to which it helps treating the tendinopathy)

Several physicians and physical therapists told me the outcome of PRP to treat a tendinopathy are roughly speaking 50/50, i.e. in 50% of patients treated with PRP, the latter seems to have helped to some degree. In the remaining 50%, PRP did not ameliorate the tendinopathy. Some evoked the possibility that chronicity influence the results, so I wonder whether any research studies addressed this question.

I am mostly interested in the lateral epicondyle of the humerus

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.